# microchip xc8 compiler (908) exit status = 1

Tags: compilation, xc8

I am working on developing dali code for 16F1947 using microchip source code provided with development boards.

I have professional version of the compiler thanks to my company, so I was able to build previous projects using PRO mode, and all optimizations offered by the build tool.

When I downloaded the dali project from microchip site, and tried to compile it using xc8 [in the PRO mode] the build fails with the error messages:

```
/opt/microchip/xc8/v1.10/bin/aspic: signal 11 
:: error: exec failed: /opt/microchip/xc8/v1.10/bin/aspic
Microchip MPLAB XC8 C Compiler (PRO Mode)  V1.10
Copyright (C) 2012 Microchip Technology Inc.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hobo/embed/mplab-x/projects/DALI_CG.X'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hobo/embed/mplab-x/projects/DALI_CG.X'
(908) exit status = 1
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/DALI_CG.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 5s)
```

The aspic is their assembler, and from microchip user manual on XC8 it is not clear what signal 11 refers to.
Further testing showed that it has something to do with their license manager xclm, because if I try to build their code without any optimizations, and in free mode, it builds fine. As we all know by now, this results in bloated code full of unnecessary loops and variables being copied back and forth.

Am I doing something stupid? Or do I just have to fork over more money and pay for the latest and greatest versions of the compiler.

Thanks beforehand,
wb

Comment: This wasn't a stupid question at all.

A toolchain shouldn't trigger an Internal compiler error / Core Dump / Segmentation fault.

Such behavior should be reported to the compiler developers/ support.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, so first, the signal 11 from the assembler means it segfaulted on input (trying to do all optimizations in the PRO version of the compiler). Obviously, in free version where it does not have to do anything it does not segfaults for obvious reasons.

I was had to upgrade to one version up (xc 1.21). Now the PRO optimization  works fine and no problems with licensing.

In retrospect, this was probably stupid question.

Sigh. I apologize.